# Copy image from Outlook and paste to Onenote is ugly

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, microsoft-onenote-2013

If I copy and paste an image and text from a ***sent*** email in Outlook to Onenote (desktop) the result is pixelated and ugly.

Pasting to Word is ok. If I paste the same into a ***new*** message, then copy the copy, and paste into Onenote the quality is the same as the original. WTF? Is there something I can do to ensure copy and paste works reliably, and without the intervening step?

(click through image for full resolution)
[image: Copy>>Paste screenshot]
[image: Copy>>Paste>>Copy>>Paste result]

More weird data points:

- selecting and copying only the image, no text, is sometimes ok
- ugly paste happens more often with older messages than new ones, i.e. a message from 2 days ago is okay by 7 days old is not

OneNote 2013 (15.0.4665.1000)
Word 2013 (15.0.4665.1000)
MSO (15.0.4675.1002) 32-bit
Windows 7 Pro SP1 x64

Answer (score 3):

After pasting to One-note right click on the image and select:
"Restore to original size" - keyboard shortcut "g".

Unfortunately I didn't found how to set this as default, Need to click that every time after "paste"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When pasting, you can choose *how* to paste: don't use CTRL+V, but open the little menu under the word Paste; try the various options for what you like.

Also, most MS Office products have a setting in their options, where you can define the default for pasting; if you never changed it, it might sit on 'assume target format'; change it to 'keep source formatting'.

Comment: I tried each of the paste options, and except for "Paste as image" they don't keep the quality, but image-paste isn't desirable because of what it does to the text. I've not been able to find the default pasting option you mention.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue, the only way around is to open the document in Word and save the bit that you want to copy as an image and then in One note insert it as an image.